# How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example for Firefox WebExtensions-API related questions?

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

The WebExtension-API for Firefox is quite complex. It is not easy to create a MWE for it.

Do you know a way how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example for Firefox WebExtensions-API related questions?

Comment: But how will I be able to FGITW your question if I can't reproduce the problem within 30 seconds by just copying and pasting everything ready-made? /s

Comment: Can you add some examples of questions that go either way? So not enough info, and too much info? Otherwise this discussion will remain too abstract, and the current answers indicate that, as they both come down to _"question askers will need to include everything that reproduces the issue"_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) must be able to reproduce the problem

Like all [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the important thing is for people reading and attempting to answer your question to be able to duplicate the problem. While it should be ***M***inimal, it also needs to provide the ***C***omplete information needed, that you've ***V***erified, to provide an ***E***xample which can **reproduce the problem**.

## A MCVE for a Firefox WebExtension or Chrome extension.

For a Firefox WebExtension, or Chrome extension, you almost always need to include your [***manifest.json***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json).

You will also need to provide enough of the rest of your code to allow the problem to be reproduced. This may include parts of, or all of:

- background scripts
- content scripts
- popup HTML/CSS
- popup scripts
- options page HTML/CSS
- option page scripts
- other scripts, CSS, or HTML
- often webpage HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

You don't always need to include all of that, but you need to include enough such that the problem can be duplicated. Which portions of the above files are actually needed, is something that can only be answered on a question by question basis.

Basically, using only the code you've provided in the question, can the problem be reproduced? You should actually create a separate project using just the code from the question and see if it duplicates the problem. That's what people who are going to be answering your question are likely to be doing, so they can see what the problem is, and give you a good answer.

### A [*manifest.json*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json) is almost always needed

Usually, for debugging questions, the most important thing is that you include your *manifest.json*. The *manifest.json* defines the environment in which the other code you are including is running. It also defines the permissions which are granted to your extension.

Sure, we don't need to know the [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/name) that you've called your extension, or the [`description`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/description) you've used, but most of the information in your *manifest.json* is needed, because it affects how your code works and what it can do.

While you can state in non-code ways much of what's included in the *manifest.json*, when you don't actually supply it, it still leaves ambiguity, even when you think there isn't. The reason for this is that the users asking questions *often* don't really understand the environment, and it's common for them to be confused about what they've set things in their *manifest.json* to do. Thus, when answering, without the *manifest.json*, you have to almost always consider that what was stated in the question as to how the asker things things are set, may be wrong.

#### Your *manifest.json* defines the contexts in which your scripts run

There are three contexts in which your script may be operating:

- **Background scripts**

  - Have full access to the extension API.
  - Can't interact with webpage content.
  - All of the following share the same context. However, for some of them the operating environment may be slightly different (e.g. you can unintentionally destroy your browser/page popup through some programmatic actions).

    - [background pages/scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)<sup><sup>([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Background_scripts))</sup></sup>
    - [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (Firefox does not support event pages. All *manifest.json* [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background) pages [remain loaded at all times](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background#Chrome_incompatibilities_2).)
    - [browser action popups](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)<sup><sup>([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction))</sup></sup>
    - [page action popups](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction)<sup><sup>([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction))</sup></sup>
    - [options pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2)<sup><sup>([MDN1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Implement_a_settings_page), [MDN2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Options_pages))</sup></sup> (in a popup, a tab, or window)
    - [sidebar action pages <sup><sup>(NDN)</sup></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/sidebarAction) (not available in Chrome)
    - Any HTML content contained within your extension which is [opened directly in a tab, window (e.g. a panel)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40839094/3773011), or frame (i.e. not as part of a web page).
- **Content scripts**

  - Have [limited access to extension APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996014/typeerror-api-is-undefined-in-content-script-or-why-cant-i-do-this-in-a-cont/40998661#40998661). Can insert Page scripts.
  - Can interact with webpage content.
- **Page scripts**

  - Have no access to extension APIs.
  - Can interact with webpage content.
  - Is in the same scope/context as web page scripts, so can interact with them (override page methods, call functions/methods, change variables, etc.).

The *manifest.json* defines which scripts are running in which context/environment, with what permissions, what HTML is loaded when a popup is displayed, etc. That information is necessary in order to understand what abilities and constraints your code is operating with/under.

---

<sup>Portions of this answer were copied from my [answer to: Communicate between scripts in the background context (background script, browser action, page action, options page, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420528/communicate-between-scripts-in-the-background-context-background-script-browse/41420772#41420772)</sup>

Comment: Note that there are some problems that are independent of the extension environment (think as "how to get the first 3 letters of a string" kind of thing) which don't require to include the extension boiler plate. Of course, you need to actually understand the problem to know what's relevant. Editors should be free to remove whatever it's relevant to the problem. Problems with using extension API's need to include more information.

Answer (score 8):

> It is not easy to create a MWE for it.

It is. It's not like a MWE/MCVE should contain *everything* to get the **application** that contains the problem at hand up and running.

If for example your question is about some Android app, the question does not have to contain all metadata and resource XML and stuff that actually packages up an Android app; all code shown should only be relevant to the question.

That is, of course, unless the question actually is about that metadata or about resource strings.

So in the scenario where your question is about a browser plugin, you are bound to have a more specific question. Changes are that the plugin part is entirely irrelevant, and that your question actually is just about JavaScript, or whatever language you write the plugin in.

Comment: Bingo. An MCVE contains everything that another developer would need to *reproduce* the problem. If they can reproduce the problem by creating a dummy plugin and pasting the code into it, that's enough. When we post an MCVE about C, we are not required to provide the answerer a C compiler, standard header files, or an operating system on which to run, even though all of those things are necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It would have been nice if you had answered this with some actual knowledge of the WebExtensions environment. The way that you have written this, it *implies* that the user doesn't need to include critical "metadata" that defines in which of the *very different* operating environments the other code included in the question is operating. This information is normally *critical* to understand what problems might exist. In a Firefox WebExtension  or Chrome extension debugging question, it is quite common for the lack of this information to make the question unanswerable.

Comment: @Makyen: News flash: not all metadata is created equal. Even you acknowledge in your answer examples of metadata that probably aren't relevant, such as name and description.

Comment: @BoltClock, Of course not. However, this question is *very explicitly* about WebExtensions. While there's some metadata provided with WebExtensions/Chrome extensions in the *manifest.json* file which doesn't matter, it's not much. As the most prolific answerer in that tag, I find it commonly an issue to get askers to supply a sufficient amount of the metadata from their *manifest.json* to make a debugging question answerable (i.e. more than 50% (guesstimate) of debugging questions don't have needed metadata). So, yeah, I'm a bit touchy about someone implying that it's OK not to include it.

Comment: Sure, that it's OK not to include metadata that affects how your code runs is probably not what @CodeCaster meant, and if they were familiar with the situation, they might have worded their answer differently. But, it's certainly how this answer can be read by naive users who are asking a question for the first time, trying to make a MCVE.

Comment: I have to agree with @Makyen. This question is asking about the expected minimum for debugging questions in the WebExtensions community here on Stack Overflow. This answer is to generalized to be useful in general, and detracts from a worthy discussion.

Comment: @Tiny no, this is not "too general" and definitely not "distracting from a worthy discussion". If you're developing an extension and have a problem caused by permissions, then you include the XML that describe the permissions. If your extension has problems with resources not being displayed, then include the resource XML. If your question is not about an options screen, then you don't have to include the options HTML. If you have a string comparison problem, this has nothing to do with it being a browser extension and all the extension stuff is irrelevant. And so on, and so on.

Comment: @Makyen _"It would have been nice if you had answered this with some actual knowledge of the WebExtensions environment"_ - it would be nice if you didn't assume I haven't.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry. My tone was a bit harsh in my 1st comment. As to assuming you lack experience in WebExtensions/Chrome extensions: It's based on: A) Your answer (and now a comment) repeatedly refer to XML based metadata, when metadata for WebExtensions is JSON, not XML. B) Your answer talks about Android apps, which WebExtensions are not (OTOH, they can run on Firefox for Android). C) You have no posts in either [tag:firefox-webextensions] or [tag:google-chrome-extension], nor any other Firefox add-on tag. So, while you may have WebExtensions experience, you're not answering from that POV.

Comment: @Makyen the format of the metadata is irrelevant. My point is that if people want debugging help, they should include the relevant details only, not dump an entire app. If extension developers generally have trouble trimming down their problem to an MCVE, which I don't know but you might given your experience in those tags, the advice should definitely not be to simply provide all code and metadata for every question. **That** is the point I'm making here.