# Where should "How to create a good reproducible example in ...?" questions reside?

Tags: discussion, questions, minimal-reproducible-example

A year or so ago, I contributed to the Stack Overflow documentation pages of [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny), where there was a good example on how to create a good [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny) Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE). I used to refer this quite frequently, because a decent amount of questions regarding [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny) do not contain an MCVE, or have a poorly formatted MCVE since [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny) code usually resides in multiple files.

However, the documentation was closed and thus that page disappeared. To close the gap, a few weeks ago I created [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-create-a-good-shiny-reproducible-example#comment84299408_48343080) so there is a set of guidelines to refer to when a Shiny question that does not have a decent MCVE is posed on SO, in line with similar questions regarding [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

However, the post currently has four close votes, suggesting to migrate to Meta. Indeed, there is also a [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361787/how-to-create-a-minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example-for-firefox-webextensio) on Meta. Although the big contrast between this question and the ones regarding [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny) and [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) seems to be that the one regarding [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox) does not contain any code at all.

So my question is; where should these kind of questions be posted?

My personal opinion: I think Stack Overflow is a good location for these kind of questions. The questions deal with code, and an MCVE can not only be useful for posting a question on Stack Overflow, but as the question regarding R states; an MCVE can be useful when "discussing performance with colleagues, teaching, sending a bug report or searching for guidance on mailing lists and here on SO".

But obviously, my opinion may be biased, so I am curious for your opinions.

Comment: I suppose I could see why this could go either way. However, in my opinion, your question would be better suited for Meta -- reason being, I see SO as a place to post problems and/or errors in code. Your question seems more like a how-to rather than an actual coding question. Though I definitely see the argument

Comment: It really depends on how the question itself is structured, and if that question *alone*, regardless of the answer, is on topic and relevant at Stack Overflow.

Comment: If the question is asked in a way that makes it independent of the use of Stackoverflow, I would definitely agree that it is on-topic on SO itself. Asking how to create a good self contained example for a certain language is a useful question. Make sure it complies to [ask] though; name the problem itself (what makes it difficult to create such example?) rather than letting the question be the preamble to a guide on how to create such examples for the use on SO.

Comment: @TreytenCarey, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest; thanks for your feedback, I agree that there is room for improvement in the phrasing of the question. For now, I have modified the question and its title to better include the problem-statement that users deal with when creating Shiny questions so that the question now more reflects the Q&A nature of Stack Overflow, rather than resembling a how-to guide.

Comment: I find that the original question, as it was originally stated, is a meta question. It's just a matter of formulation, though. One could edit it and remove the part of introspection on the question itself. The part actually similar to the other "how to make a good [insert topic here]"  is a good thing. IMO. It starts being too meta for me when there is discussion about the question itself in its own body.

Comment: possibly related: [Process for nominating and promoting canonical questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276010/839601)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a self-answered canonical question be posted on Meta Stack Overflow instead of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357257/should-a-self-answered-canonical-question-be-posted-on-meta-stack-overflow-inste)

Comment: Most people seem to agree that this Q&A is more appropriate for SO than for Meta. I have converted my answer to a community wiki to avoid creating a wrong impression. However, one thing I am still doubting about; The first four lines of the question make the Q&A more meta, but I do think it adds value to the question. Should I remove those lines anyway? Curious for your opinions.

Comment: @Florian Thanks for coming back to wrap this up. Given that nobody has unilaterally edited the intro out, and that there doesn't appear to be any _strong_ feelings on the issue here, I guess you're safe to leave it as it is.

Comment: I dont think minimal examples are useful for SO only, e.g. communication, code testing, documentation. Very useful for SO doesnt make it off topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've already seen, we have a few similar "FAQ" questions on the main site:

1. [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag (this one is almost 7 years old with thousands of views and votes), and
2. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) (this is relatively new, but has still accumulated a few hundred votes)

From the perspective of a pandas user, I cannot imagine the state of the questions in this tag had the FAQ question *not* been created. The Q&A has been instrumental in educating users on how to ask *good*, *on topic* questions on this tag.

It is important to understand that not every tag is the same, and the criteria that determine how on-topic a question is to that tag depends on criteria that may or may not be covered by the general FAQ. Us pandas users have added this question as "Recommended Reading" in the FAQ tag, and frequently direct askers of poor questions to this link so they may better understand how to re-word their question to fit in with the norms of the tag (and the site as a whole).

The answer to your question, "where should these kind of questions be posted?" is really "it depends", and should be handled on a case-by-case basis. The [general FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) only explains what you must do to ask a good question. The "what" part is covered, but the "how", isn't, and that would differ by the tag. Some tags have a more complicated answer to the "how" than others, and a FAQ question on the main site would be particularly useful for those.

Personally, I *do not* have a problem with FAQ questions, as long people read them, and they help improve the quality of questions on the site by educating users on how to better ask solid, on-topic questions with reproducible examples.

Comment: Most of your arguments pertain to the existence or non-existence of a FAQ, not what site it should live on.

Comment: @Axeman I did: "and a FAQ question on the main site would be particularly useful for those.".

Comment: The first one is closed for off-topic, apparently by people never write R.

Answer (score 5):

The entire first paragraph and arguably the first sentence of the second paragraph refer to asking questions on Stack Overflow ([at the current revision, 6](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48343080/6)). This is the very [definition of "meta"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Ameta&rlz=1C1CHZL_enGB689GB689&oq=define%3Ameta&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.2065j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ("referring to itself").

That said, it seems to me that the content I mentioned is unnecessary preamble - every word of it. If that content were to be removed and the question tweaked slightly a case could be made that it is no longer meta as it would then be about reproducible examples *in general*.

Answer (score 5):

You should not make it on-site as they did for [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r). Useful as that post may be, it is actually not on-topic on SO. When it comes to FAQs, many language tags have implemented questionable FAQ systems that go against the SO policies overall (as I noted when we [created a FAQ for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349241/creating-a-c-faq-tag) [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)): meta tags and meta posts on the main site etc. The alternative would be to post it here on meta, but then it will be a pain to find for the people who need it.

Therefore, the best place is probably to post it at the tag wiki. Add a "tag usuage" headline where you briefly explain that SO expects code examples of a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) nature. Followed by a description about how to best do this given the specific technology.

Comment: The tag wiki could also point to a post on Meta. How content would be divided between the two locations would be up for discussion. A post on Meta could offer various examples via multiple answers. It is also possible to include code examples with syntax highlighting within a tag wiki.

Comment: +1 I prefer this suggestion, quite frankly, with my own coming second. Even with the edits I suggested the question would still be at least a bit "meta". In the tag wiki or a link from the tag wiki to this site seems like a more appropriate place for it than on SO proper.