# What is the prefered way to share a dataframe on Stack Overflow to increase potentional for assistance?

Tags: discussion

I have a fairly complex problem I'm trying to work through dealing with [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) and Python - and I have data frames of sample data that I'm loading into pandas from an Excel file. To share some sample data - I need to share this data here in a question. What is an appropriate way to share a dataframe to increase the odds of someone assisting me and being capable of reproducing my data set?

I've used msgpack to export the dataframe to a file - but that file isn't plaintext and I'd have to upload it somewhere. It seems problematic to me.

Is there a way in pandas to export a dataframe to a Pandas statement that could be used to recreate the dataframe from Python? What other options do I have? I don't think typing out this sample data is feasible, unfortunately.

*There isn't any *Pandas* tag on meta to ask this question.

Comment: check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Could upload it on Google drive and provide the link with the question you want to ask?

Comment: @CHAMISoufiane no, because that won’t work long term. Questions need to be self contained and useful for future visitors and a broken link to a google drive location that no longer exists will happen and will invalidate the question.

Answer (score 35):

This is already well-covered in [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). If you feel the need for others to have access to full versions of all your dataframes then it indicates that you haven't got to grips with the problem at all on your end, and the question is likely too broad. It's your job to narrow down the issue before posting.

Comment: I flagged that question for migration to Meta.

Comment: @jpmc26 I have a feeling it has been discussed a few times in the past. My Meta search is bad enough at the best of times, but I don't have chance to track down the discussion (if it does exist) right now.

Comment: [One example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363046/where-should-how-to-create-a-good-reproducible-example-in-questions-resid)

Comment: @AndrasDeak That discussion suggests that the question is appropriate, meaning it shouldn't be closed. Either it should be open or it should be on Meta. It shouldn't be closed and on the main site.

Comment: The question you're referring to is flagged as *off topic* which I find odd given that it serves as a *well-covered* example on how to do something on SO.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger I'm not sure I understand your point. The fact that the information may better be migrated to Meta says nothing about whether the content of that post is relevant to this OP's inquiry about how to present data in a reproducible dataframe example.

Comment: @jpmc26 that question SHOULD NOT be on meta, because making reproducible pandas examples _is_ related to programming and **is not specific to Stack Overflow**. When opening an issue on GitHub, or just posting for help elsewhere on the net, you need to know how to make a good repro.

Comment: @richardec it's been 2 and a half years since this discussion happened, and clearly things have changed since then (look at the flag on the post). I'm pretty sure things are done here

Comment: I'm fully aware, I thought I'd just put that note there in case someone else read here ;)